# Javascript if string contains specific number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my site alert if the number 39 contains a string

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
if(a[i].innerHTML.indexOf("39") !== -1){
    var val = a[i].innerHTML.split('    ').join('');
    alert(val);
    if(val == "39"){
        alert("gg");
    }
}
}
```

var a is "                  39  " and "     39,5            "
39 and 39,5 is surrounded by spaces.

how do i make it so it only displays 39 and not both?

Comment: O__o?..........

Comment: I'm really not sure what's happening in this question - It might help to include more about [the problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: I can't answer because the question is on hold but use this regex `/(?!39.5)39/g.test(val)`, will return true if 39 but false if 39.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Is that what you were looking for?

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var val = a[i].innerText.split(' ');
  var index = val.indexOf("39");
  if (index !== -1) {
    console.log(val[index]);
    alert("gg");
  }
}
```

```html
<div>38 38.5 39 39.5</div>
<div>40 41 42 43</div>
```

Comment: The OP already test with indexOf why test another time with includes?

Comment: shit forgot the question part lol nvm how do i make it so it only displays 39?

Comment: But OP does not wan't 39.5 (I think,The question is bad.)

Comment: so why don't test 39.5 exactly? I don't understand sorry guys

Comment: I forgot to tell you this buy the 2 numbers are between alot of spaces so "    
    39                      " and "    39,5                    "

Comment: Soooo `parseInt("   39.5  ")`?  Removes the spaces, returns `39`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tcfbgQsYtM

Comment: Try it now, I don't know if that's what you need.

Comment: well its not quite that

Comment: I have 5 option(s)

one with spacespacespace39spacespace
one with spacespacespace39,5spacespace
one with spacespacespace40spacespace

I wan it to only alert me when it found 39 exact

Comment: @Samhakadas Then just change about of spaces that separates numbers and you will find what you were looking for.